# How to use mapPartitions in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to use `mapPartitions` in Scala but getting the following error.

```
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: Iterator[?]
[error] Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
[error]         rdd.mapPartitions(showParts)
```

I call the `mapPartitions` function as follows.

```
rdd.mapPartitions(showParts)
```

Where `showParts` function is defined as follows.

```
def showParts(iter: Iterator[(Long, Array[String])]) = 
{ 
  while (iter.hasNext)
  {
    val cur = iter.next;
    // Do something with cur
  }
}
```

What is the proper way of using `mapPartitions` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the UDF you pass to `mapPartitions` has to have a return type of `Iterator[U]`. Your current code does not return anything and thus is of type `Unit`.

If you want to obtain an empty `RDD` after performing the `mapPartitions` then you can do the following:

```scala
def showParts(iter: Iterator[(Long, Array[String])]) = 
{ 
  while (iter.hasNext)
  {
    val cur = iter.next;
    // Do something with cur
  }

  // return Iterator[U]
  Iterator.empty 
}
```

Comment: Is it also possible to return an Array?

Comment: You can always convert an `Array` into an `Iterator` by calling `toIterator` on the array, e.g. `Array(1,2,3,4).toIterator` gives you an `Iterator[Int]`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return an `Iterator` from your `showParts` function.

```
def onlyEven(numbers: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[Int] = 
  numbers.filter(_ % 2 == 0)

def partitionSize(numbers: Iterator[Int]) : Iterator[Int] = 
  Iterator.single(numbers.length)

val rdd = sc.parallelize(0 to 10)
rdd.mapPartitions(onlyEven).collect()
// Array[Int] = Array(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10)

rdd.mapPartitions(size).collect()
// Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: Is it possible to return an Array?